# Get all images from folder and set them in a list?

Tags: unity

How to Load images from folder and set them in a List?
[image]

```
public List<GameObject> Img_Re = new List<GameObject>();

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    // Folder path "Assets/Images/Enemies"
}
```

Update 1:
Here is an image from unity editor.

I tried to find a solution from using "Resources.LoadAll" but did not give me anything!!

Comment: The "Assets/Images/Enemies" folder does not exist in the built version of your game. Assets that were referenced by something get combined into asset files, and assets that were not get skipped. If you want to load images that exist at Edit time, you should not do it in Start. If you want to load images that do not exist at Edit time, you should not load them from "Assets/". Can you edit your question to clarify how this is being used in your project so we can propose suitable solutions?

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply and the information. I updated my question. In Start() or Update() method is fine for me. What I need is to load and set them in my list.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this at runtime? Do you expect this list of images to change after the game is built and installed on a player's hard drive?

Comment: Look, I'm working on puzzle 2d game like "Slide Number Puzzle". Now I have around 15 levels. Every level has around 16-25 images. Instead of drag-drop in my list, I want this script to load all images from the folder and set them in my list. So, to answer your question, "Why are you trying to do this at runtime?" Because I'm lazy.... I don't want to drag-drop every image manually. So, which method is good for the game? Do it manually, or use script to load all images?

Comment: You can do this with a single drag and drop, or an editor script that runs at edit time, not during runtime.

Comment: Resources.Load / LoadAll works only for assets under a folder named "Resources", so it sounds to me like you were just using it incorrectly. Better to avoid using it though - there are better ways to do this, as I've shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easiest to do with no scripting at all. Just make your list variable:

```
public List<Sprite> enemySprites;
// or public Sprite[] enemySprites; would work just as well.
```

Select the object holding this script that you want to populate, and click the lock icon at the top-right of the Inspector pane so that it closes: →

[image: Lock icon at top of Inspector]

Now go select all the sprites you want to assign from your Project pane. You can click on the first one, then hold shift and click on the last one to select everything in the folder in two clicks.

Because the Inspector is locked, clicking on these sprites won't navigate away from showing the list you want to populate.

[image: Dragging sprites into list]

Now you can drag your selection of all those sprites over the `Enemy Sprites` field in the inspector to assign them all to the list in one go.

[image: All sprites assigned]

But if you really want to do it via script, you can tackle it like so:

```
using UnityEngine;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif


public class ListOfSprites : MonoBehaviour
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    public string spriteFolder = "Textures/Enemies";

    void OnValidate() {
        string fullPath = $"{Application.dataPath}/{spriteFolder}";
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(fullPath)) {            
            return;
        }

        var folders = new string[]{$"Assets/{spriteFolder}"};
        var guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:Sprite", folders);

        var newSprites = new Sprite[guids.Length];

        bool mismatch;
        if (enemySprites == null) {
            mismatch = true;
            enemySprites = newSprites;
        } else {
            mismatch = newSprites.Length != enemySprites.Length;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < newSprites.Length; i++) {
            var path = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guids[i]);
            newSprites[i] = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Sprite>(path);
            mismatch |= (i < enemySprites.Length && enemySprites[i] != newSprites[i]);
        }

        if (mismatch) {
            enemySprites = newSprites;
            Debug.Log($"{name} sprite list updated.");
        }        
    }
    #endif

    public Sprite[] enemySprites;
}
```

Because this runs in `OnValidate`, it updates any time you change the `spriteFolder` field in the Inspector, at edit time. The resulting list is then serialized into the built version of the game, so there's no searching for the right assets at runtime - you've already stored explicit references to the ones you need.

Comment: Thank you so much, DMGregory.

Comment: Brilliant. This allows the editor to populate a list of <T> by just pointing to a path.