# How to load a whole folder of assets without using a Resources folder?

Tags: unity, assets, editors, asset-workflow

I have a folder full of images that I want to keep ready in a script. The Unity way to do this is to have a `MonoBehaviour` with, for example, a `Sprite[]` field, which I can populate in the editor.

Unfortunately, this also means that I have to sync my component manually with the folder's contents.

Essentially I'm looking for a way to "compile" this array at build time and avoid using the `Resources` folder approach, as I would like this to be loaded before the scene is started.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/201164/get-all-images-from-folder-and-set-them-in-a-list something like this?

Comment: @Zibelas OMG! Yes! I did not know that you can drag multiple assets onto an array like that. The editor script seems even nicer.